# How to replace multiline comments with sed in files

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have all sort of files `php html xml` where the `copyright` notice is included either in `top` or after 2-3 lines from the top like this

```
/**
 * Copyright (c)  2014
 * All rights reserved.
 * bla bla many lines like this
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
```

Now i want to remove all that text from all the files.

How can i remove with sed.

I just know basic `sed` but i don't know how to deal with multilines

Comment: Do you have `c++` comments in `xml` or `html` too?

Comment: @Birei no in html, xml i have `<!--` before that

Comment: "basic" sed is 100% all you want/need to use sed for. Sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions **on a single line**, for anything else you should use awk. If you find yourself using more than the s, g, and p (with -n) commands in sed then you are using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat file
1
2
/**
 * Copyright (c)  2014
 * All rights reserved.
 * bla bla many lines like this
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
3
4
/* and here is another comment
 * you presumably want to keep
 */
5
6

$ awk '/^\/\*/{c++} c!=1; /^ \*\//{c++}' file
1
2
3
4
/* and here is another comment
 * you presumably want to keep
 */
5
6
```

Answer (score 3):

In [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) you can delete a range starting with `/*` and ending with `*/` like this:

```
sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d inputFile
```

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) tends to be a bit hard to read sometimes, so I'll  give a more clear example: If you want to delete everything in a range starting with `abc` and ending with `xyz`, you'd do

```
sed '/abc/,/def/d' inputFile
```

The case with `/*` and `*/` is the same, but `/` and `*` have to be escaped.

A similar approach should work for the [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [php](/questions/tagged/php) files.

Comment: don't work when we have the text on the same line, because eats next line